# How to build Hello-World project with maven structure?

Tags: java, maven

I am new with java and start to reading maven but the document is not clear for me. I have a simple Hello-World project like so  :

```
package main;

public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I want to implement this in maven structure  .What should I do for this ?
 I download and install appache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip and set the environment variable  .

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html, https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html. What is unclear?

Comment: The next step - read the docs.

Comment: @janos I read the document but still I have a problem  .In my main program I should use an external Interface that is in Jar file format  .means my project depend on a jar file I don't know how to handle it

Comment: @gotlini you asked for a "hello-world project" with Maven structure. Your comment is asking for something completely different, that belongs in a different question.

Comment: @ janos I know I extend my project and now I have the problem said in last comment

Answer (score 0):

[See this page.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/)

Using this command:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

It will generate a new directory `my-app` that is a complete Maven project with the recommended layout, that is:

```
$ find my-app/
my-app/
my-app//pom.xml
my-app//src
my-app//src/main
my-app//src/main/java
my-app//src/main/java/com
my-app//src/main/java/com/mycompany
my-app//src/main/java/com/mycompany/app
my-app//src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java
my-app//src/test
my-app//src/test/java
my-app//src/test/java/com
my-app//src/test/java/com/mycompany
my-app//src/test/java/com/mycompany/app
my-app//src/test/java/com/mycompany/app/AppTest.java
```

Customize the `groupId` and `artifactId` according to your needs.

See [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for more details about the layout.